# CakePHP Logging to Live DB During Unit Testing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using DB logging in Cake 2.1, which works great.

The problem I'm having is when running Unit Tests, all logs are still getting sent to the live db rather than the test database.

All other db interactions go to test, except logging.

I do have a log fixture created and imported into the test case.

Here's my Database logger (/Lib/Log/Engine/DatabaseLogger.php)

```
App::uses('CakeLogInterface', 'Log');

class DatabaseLogger implements CakeLogInterface
{
    public function __construct($options = array() )
    {
        App::import('Model', 'Log');
        $this->Log = new Log;
    }

    public function write($type, $message)
    {
        $this->Log->create();

        $log['type'] = ucfirst($type);
        $log['date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $log['message'] = $message;

        return $this->Log->save($log);
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing some basic setting here but I can't figure this out for the life of me.

Comment: Nobody's got anything on this?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you fix it?

Comment: Nope. Can't get a response anywhere. I've noticed any DB interaction in tests will go into the production DB if I don't have Fixtures defined for a particular model, but this one has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case the problem was caused because of a bad initialization of a constructor.
You can check the update solution here:
[How to choose the test DB cakePHP testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112167/how-to-choose-the-test-db-cakephp-testing/10174319#10174319)

And here: 
[How to override model's constructor correctly in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153841/how-to-overriding-a-constructor-correctly-at-cakephp-2-0)