# How to override model's constructor correctly in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, testing, constructor, overwrite

I have troubles with testing Model in CakePHP 2.0 and it seems the problem is on the model's constructor.

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->_pagi_cuantos = 2;
}
```

Even if I delete all its content, I still getting problems trying to run the test.

Mark Story told me:

> if you have a constructor make sure you're overriding the constructor
>   correctly. Failing to do so will cause errors like this.

What do I wrong?

Comment: What happens? You'll have to give us something more to go on if you want help...

Comment: Well, what happen should be irrelevant. But if you want to know it: the testCase doesn't select well the Database. It works with the default one when it should work with the test one. (btw, i have updated the post)

Comment: This problem is actual for all versions of CakePHP. I faced the same in 1.3

Answer (score 20, accepted):

why don't you look into the core code
its open source after all:
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.1/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L653

so for all your models:

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
}
```

Comment: This is also mentioned in the CakePHP 2.0 API documentation for [Overriding Model's __construct method](https://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-AppModel.html#___construct)

Answer (score 6):

Rather than override the constructor, how about using beforeFilter() for controllers or the before methods for the Model such as beforeFind(), beforeValidate(), etc.

Answer (score 1):

One way that I found is to do something like this:

```
function __construct() {
    call_user_func_array(array('parent', '__construct'), func_get_args());
}
```

It allows you to not have to worry about what the parent gets passed.  Although that code is pretty hideous.