# How does one turn off logging during unit testing in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

If you are unit testing a model, for instance, and in that model you use CakePHP's CakeLog convenience method (perhaps testing an expected exception, etc):

```
CakeLog::warning('This is a warning');
```

Cake will not only output this at the command line during your test, it will also add the error to logs/error.log.

I need to accomplish one of two things:

1. Turn off logging during unit testing
2. Mock the CakeLog class or stub Model->log() (inherited from Object->log)

How does a savvy CakePHP developer accomplish one of these two things?

Related: [Using DB logging and doing said logging to your test database where such a thing wouldn't bother you...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952001/cakephp-logging-to-live-db-during-unit-testing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of your test, put `CakeLog::drop(logger_name);` to [disable logging on the logger_name](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html) stream